# After rejecting item, workflow continues to work

Tags: workflow, 2013

I start an approval process and there is 3 participates. Each of them `one at a time (serial)`. It works fine when they all approve the item. But when first or second person reject it, workflow continues to work and sen task to the next person.

It has to be completed when someone reject the item. How can I make it happen?

Answer (score 1):

In Task Behaviors, I put `End Task Process` action into the else branch of the Rejected part in `When a Task Completes`.